# Strange abbreviation for multivariable chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

(using Einstein's summation convention) I'm reading general relativity book of Sean Carroll, in which he states this

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^l$. We can label points in each space in terms of components: $x^a$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$, $x^b$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x^c$ on $\mathbb{R}^l$, where the indices range over the appropriate values. The chain rule relates the partial derivatives of the composition to the partial derivatives of the individual maps: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}(g\circ f)^c=\frac{\partial f^b}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial g^c}{\partial y^b}$$
> **This is usually abbreviated to** $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}=\frac{\partial y^b}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^b}$$

Why? I don't understand the reason for this abbreviation at all. Does $\frac{\partial y^b}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^b}(g\circ f)^c$ somehow simplify to $\frac{\partial f^b}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial g^c}{\partial y^b}$?

Comment: Yes somehow. I think Carroll could (maybe should) have used $y$ for the map $f$ as the chain rule indicates. $g$ lives on $\mathbb R^n$ with coordinates $y$ and $f$ (aka $y$) is a chart for $\mathbb R^n$ with coordinates $x\,.$ Reduce it to the simple case of $\mathbb R^2$ with Cartesian and  polar coordinates.

Comment: Should $x^b$ be $y^b$, and similarly $x^c$ be $z^c$...? <> Whether or no, writing the chain rule in Leibniz notation generally suppresses points where a derivative is evaluated. Here, for example, the left-hand side is evaluated at $x$; on the right, however, the partial of $g^c$ w.r.t. $y^b$ is evaluated at $f(x)$, while the partial of $f^b$ w.r.t. $x^a$ is evaluated at $x$. But if we squint, then $(g\circ f)^c$ and $g^c$ are sort of the same thing ("the function $g$", or "the variable $z^c$"), and can be dropped from both sides.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: But even with that logic, why does $f^b$ get replaced by $y^b$? Is there any actual utility for this abbreviation? As an operator, $\partial/\partial x^a$ makes sense for component functions of a $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ function. e.g. it makes all the sense to apply operator $\partial/\partial x^a$ on $f^b$. And let's say that I apply this operator on a composite of 2 functions, then isn't the RHS of the first equation enough to paint a clear picture? What is the point of framing it like the RHS of the second equation?

Comment: The way this "variables and mappings notation" works, $y^b=f^b(x)$; if we squint here, "$y^b = f^b$." <> Literally, $f^b = y^b \circ f$: When we write a vector-valued function as a list of components, each component is the mapping $f$ followed by projection to a coordinate. (If that looks surprising or wrong you're far from alone! Anyway, it's worth pondering these details, if only to see what a nuisance it is to be literal in multivariable calculus. :)